# set model in django admin to allow anonymous access

Tags: django, authorization

I currently have some models setup that I would like to be read only if the logged in user is anonymous. I assume I have to first figure out how to allow models to be viewable by anonymous users first. Currently user has to be logged in and set as a staff user.

Comment: Noooooooo. Please dont do that. Though it might be more work, please create new pages that could allow access.. The whole idea of the admin interface is for super user access only.

Comment: Please don't utilize django admin as a tool that allows unauthorized users to view content? That was the whole purpose. Please give more elaborate answers on why it's a bad idea and what I can do.